# 90's Kid's cartoon book where kid gets teleported to an alien planet during a laser tag game

Tags: story-identification

I remember reading a book as a child about a kid who was playing a laser tag tournament or something of that nature when he gets teleported to an alien planet.

Once there he ends up fighting for those people in what seems to be a real laser battle and helps them win. Once he does he's teleported back to earth where he ends up getting hit and losing his laser tag game.

Comment: So, did it have cartoonish illustrations? Was it based on a cartoon? Was it a comic book format?

Answer (score 3):

This is one of the novels based on the mid-to-late 80s television series [***Photon***](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon_(TV_series)).

The main character is Christopher Jarvis, a teenaged laser tag player who is transported to an alien space station and then to a variety of alien worlds to fight as a "Photon Warrior".

There were two series of novels, one written by **Peter David** and another by **Michael Hudson** (pseudonym for **Michael P. Kube-McDowell**).  David was responsible for the adult-aimed series and Kube-McDowell for the junior series.

It sounds like you read the first novel of one of these two series, each of which covers Jarvis' first adventure as a Photon Warrior.  The first book of the adult series was Peter David's [***Photon: For the Glory***](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/4378974-for-the-glory) (aka ***Photon #1***)

[image]

and the first book of the junior series was Michael Hudson's [***Photon: Thieves of Light***](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/4378975-thieves-of-light)

[image]

Comment: There were adult ones written by Peter David and young adult ones by Michael P. Kube-McDowell under the house name Michael Hudson.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots : Added in Hudson, thanks.

Comment: It is. I figured I'd go in on the pseudonyms.

Comment: Weirdly enough, the Peter David ones (often misattributed to David Peters) had more cartoonish covers than the YA series.